# Autofill sharepoint list form based on currently filtered field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I have 2 lists that are connected.  When I filter List A by ProjectID, I get results in List B only for that projectID.

What I am trying to do is, let's say the List A filter is on Project ID: 1.

When I go to add a new item to List B, the field 'Project ID' will automatically be filled with ID 1.

Any ideas on ways to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Is ProjectId a lookUp column in ListB?
If not and you are using the default edit form of SharePoint then it is not straight forward. I think the easiest approach would be InfoPath form if you are allowed to publish them in your SharePoint environment.

Comment: Projectid is not currently a lookup column but I suppose I could change that if necessary.  Any suggestions on how to go about doing it that way?

Comment: 1. Create ProjectidLookUp column in List B. 2. While creating the lookup column, you can add any additional column from List A. I am sorry if I misunderstood the question. But this is what I can suggest you. :) Let me know if this does not help.